# How to add a Block Grid with Mass Action in an UI form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, admin

I have UI form with a Block grid.

```
<fieldset name="profile_products">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="in_profile_products">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">amazon_profile_form_data_source</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Selected Products</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <container name="profile_products_container_grid">
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Ui\Form\Product</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>


namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Ui\Form;

class Product extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    /**
     * Block template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'MyVendor_MyModule::profile/product.phtml';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
     */
    protected $blockGrid;


    /**
     * Retrieve instance of grid block
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getBlockGrid()
    {
        if (null === $this->blockGrid) {
            $this->blockGrid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Ui\Form\Product\Grid::class,
                'mymodule.admin.profile.product.grid'
            );
        }
        return $this->blockGrid;
    }
}
```

**Grid.php**

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Ui\Form\Product;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{ .....
}
```

**products.phtml**

```
   $block->getGridHtml()
```

For reference: [Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/category/edit/assign_products.phtml)

I need to add a mass-action bar and select-all option in selection checkbox.